# Problema para remover elemento de lista encadeada em C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

A minha função só estão removendo o primeiro elemento se eu informar o nome desse primeiro elemento. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para a função achar o elemento e removê-lo. A função de inserir esta funcionando então não vou coloca-la.. 
**Segue o código:**

```
typedef struct TLista
{
    struct TLista *prox;
    char nome[30];
    char end[40];
    int idade;
}TLista;

typedef TLista *PLista;

PLista inicializa()
{
    return NULL;
}
PLista remover(PLista p)
{
    PLista ant = NULL;
    PLista aux = p;
    char name[60], name2[60];
    getchar();
    strcpy(name2, aux->nome);
    strlwr(name2);
    printf("\nEntre com o nome que deseja remover: ");
    gets(name);
    strlwr(name);
    while(aux!=NULL && strcmp(name, name2) !=0)
    {
        ant = aux;
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
    if (aux == NULL || p == NULL)
    {
        return p;
    }
    else if(ant == NULL)
    {
        p = aux->prox;
    }
    else if(aux->prox == NULL)
    {
        ant->prox = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        ant->prox = aux->prox;
    }
    printf("\n      Nome removido com sucesso!\n\n");
    free(aux);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo pelo seu código que a lista não admite elementos com nomes iguais...
Acredito que essa solução resolve seu problema.

Bons estudos =)

```
PLista remover(PLista p)
{
    //lista vazia
    if(p == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    char name[60], name2[60];
    printf("\nEntre com o nome que deseja remover: ");
    gets(name);
    strlwr(name);

    PLista ant = NULL;
    PLista aux = p;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        //como observou fabiano esta linha fica dentro do laco
        strcpy(name2, aux->nome);
        strlwr(name2);

        if(strcmp(name, name2) == 0)
            break;

        ant = aux;
        aux = aux->prox;
    }

    //se ant for null entao o elemento a ser removido é o primeiro ... esse caso precisa de tratamento especial
    if(ant == NULL){
        p = p->prox;
        printf("\n\tNome removido com sucesso!\n\n");
        free(aux);
    }
    //aux for diferente de NULL entao o while parou antes do fim da lista (Logo existe elemento com nome igual ao fornecido)
    else if(aux != NULL){
        ant = aux->prox; //ant agora aponta para o elemento que sucede aux
        printf("\n\tNome removido com sucesso!\n\n");
        free(aux);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Seria um bom exercício criar uma lista com nomes repetidos e remover todos eles.

Comment: 2 meses atrás lol

Answer (score 1):

```
strcmp(name2, aux->nome);
```

Essa linha tem de estar dentro do for, para que cada nó atualize o valor de name2 se não você sempre vai comparar o nome do primeiro elemento, dai o motivo de você só consegui excluir o primeiro.